# Raspbian can't mount samba share on router

Tags: raspbian, samba, share

I have a usb drive connected to my router, it's a share, works fine from all our windows machines and from Ubuntu, but not from Raspbian. I got the IP-address with `nmblookup -S WORKGROUP` and the path with `smbtree -N`, and I can list it:

```
pi@RPi2a ~ $ /usr/bin/smbclient -L //192.168.2.253/SMBSHARE -N  
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.3.14]  

        Sharename       Type      Comment  
        ---------       ----      -------  
        samba           Disk      samba share dir  
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server)  
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.3.14]  

        Server               Comment  
        ---------            -------  
        MY_LT  
        RPI2A                RPi2a server  
        SMBSHARE             Samba Server  

        Workgroup            Master  
        ---------            -------  
        WORKGROUP            SMBSHARE
```

I'm trying to mount it with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.253/SMBSHARE/samba/usb1_1 /mnt/pishare --verbose -o guest
```

Resulting in:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.2.253,unc=\\192.168.2.253\SMBSHARE,guest,user=,prefixpath=SAMBA/USB1_1,pass=********  
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

Trying to find a solution, I came across [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118115/cant-mount-samba-share) (among many many others). Trying to connect with smbclient:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/smbclient \\\\192.168.2.253\\SMBSHARE\\samba\usb1_1 -Nd=3
```

I get:

```
...  
Connecting to 192.168.2.253 at port 445  
Connecting to 192.168.2.253 at port 139  
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.3.14]  
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

I should add that Samba does run on the RPi, for sharing some folders on the Pi itself. As I understood, `cifs` doesn't use `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, the `smbclient` command is just for checking permissions. But I don't even get there. Should I pass more parameters to smbclient?

I don't understand why mount.cifs can't find the share, when smbclient -L does list it properly. Nor do I see how permissions enter into it, as I can successfully browse and read everything from Windows and Ubuntu without credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The mount needs to be of the form `//<server>/<share>`.  From the `smbclient -L` output, the relevant parts are:

```
        Sharename       Type      Comment  
        ---------       ----      -------  
        samba           Disk      samba share dir  
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server)  
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.3.14]  

        Server               Comment  
        ---------            -------  
        MY_LT  
        RPI2A                RPi2a server  
        SMBSHARE             Samba Server
```

As `$IPC$` is a default share, the likely only valid share here is `samba`.  The server can be identified either via the IP (192.168.2.253) or by name (SMBSHARE).

Unfortunately in the mount command, the two are combined, both in

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.253/SMBSHARE/samba/usb1_1 /mnt/pishare --verbose -o guest
```

and in

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/smbclient \\\\192.168.2.253\\SMBSHARE\\samba\usb1_1 -Nd=3
```

The double server portion is incorrect.  It should be `//192.168.2.253/samba/...` or `//SMBSHARE/samba/...`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
-o guest
```

as your *mount* option, try

```
-o username=guest,password=foo,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noserverino
```

(password can be anything you want, but it **can't** be empty.)

This is a fairly recent change in CIFS support, and in my experience older guest network shares needed to be changed over to use these options.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't fix it, alas. I checked the cifs-utils install as per [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/336739/83967), and I tried with `,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,port=445` appended, and verified that port 445 is listening. Still I get `mount error(6): No such device or address`. Am now going to wade through `man mount.cifs`.